# ionic v3 angular v5 cant pass CSRF to php Slim server

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, slim

I have made PHP [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) server. Authentication for it and [CSRF](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf).
I want to use it as a REST Server.

I have a created an App using [IonicFramework](https://ionicframework.com/framework) which uses [Angular](https://angular.io/).

I want to authenticate myself with this code

```
let hheaders:Headers=new Headers();
    hheaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    hheaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    hheaders.append('Accept','application/json');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:hheaders});

     let data = new FormData();
     data.append("email", this.myForm.email);
     data.append("password", this.myForm.password);
     data.append("csrf_name", this.myForm.csrf_name);
     data.append("csrf_value", this.myForm.csrf_value);

     return this.http.post('http://10.1.3.101:8088/public/auth/signinservice',data,this.options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .toPromise();
```

But I always get `Failed CSRF check!` I do not know what is the problem. At this point the Slim Server is basic. It is very simple and similar to this [Github project](https://github.com/2karis/Php-login-and-Registration-System/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php) with new methods in `AuthController.php`
like

```
public function getSignInService($request, $response){

        $nameKey = $this->csrf->getTokenNameKey();
        $valueKey = $this->csrf->getTokenValueKey();
        $name = $request->getAttribute($nameKey);
        $value = $request->getAttribute($valueKey);

        $tokenArray = [
            $nameKey => $name,
            $valueKey => $value
        ];


    return $response->write(json_encode($tokenArray));
    }
```

and

```
   public function postSignInService($request, $response, $args){



        $auth = $this->auth->attempt(

            $request->getParam('email'),
            $request->getParam('password')

        );

        if(!$auth){
            $data = array('status' => 'error');
            $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 203);
            return $newResponse;


        }


        $data = array('status' => 'Successful login');
        $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 200);
        return $newResponse;
    }
```

and added routes for the methods.

How could i successfully authenticate with Ionic v3 and Angular v5?